# After suspend mode, Wi-Fi won't reconnect to open network, but works fine on secure network. Any suggestions?

Tags: wireless, suspend, password, macbook

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a 2007 MacBook. Wi-Fi works perfectly at home on my passworded Wi-Fi network, including after I suspend.

But at a coffee shop which has two open Wi-Fi networks, the Wi-Fi won't reconnect after I close the lid on the laptop. Also, the computer goes into some sort of low-power mode (screen dims), which forces me to stop working (even off my hard drive).

Meanwhile, it works fine when I return home.

I know from reading other posts there is a Wi-Fi / suspend bug, but I haven't heard of the problem occurring exclusively on open Wi-Fi networks (no password) while not occurring on a password-secured network. And I haven't seen any references to it effectively rendering the computer unusable.

Any suggestions for a workaround that doesn't involve opening a terminal or installing a new kernel by itself? (I install all official Ubuntu updates immediately, but I'm not a technical person and I have no command line competence.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution :P I have problems with wifi even at my home, if the signal gets lost and then up again then the wifi, sometimes, can't reconnect (even with disabling-enabling wifi). The only thing I can do is run in terminal 'systemctl restart NetworkManager' and the wifi works again. You can create a .desktop file on your desktop with this command so that you execute it every time you have problem.